# Apple Health Kit Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5 “Authorization not determined”

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, healthkit

I hava determined authorization before actually trying to access the user's dateofBirth and biologicalSex. But it's work on simulator.but not on iphone and paired watch.

```
    let birthdayType = HKQuantityType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.dateOfBirth)
    let biologicalSexType = HKQuantityType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.biologicalSex)
    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)
    let readDataTypes: Set<HKObjectType> =  [quantityType!, birthdayType!, biologicalSexType!]
    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() == true else {
        label.setText("not available")
        return
    }

    let readDataTypes: Set<HKObjectType> = self.dataTypesToRead()

    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: readDataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success == false {
            self.displayNotAllowed()
        }
    }

    var birthDay: Date! = nil
    do {
       birthDay = try self.healthStore.dateOfBirth()
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("Either an error occured fetching the user's age information or none has been stored yet. \(error)")
        return -1
    }
    var biologicalSex:HKBiologicalSexObject! = nil
    do {
        try biologicalSex = self.healthStore.biologicalSex()
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Failed to read the biologicalSex! \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a concurrency problem, not a HealthKit problem.

`requestAuthorization` may display a dialog and gives you the result in a background process.

You have to wait for the answer of `requestAuthorization` before you continue reading birthday and biologicalSex.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved the problem.The version of  my watchOS is 2.2.1. It couldn't sync the data of healthstore between watch and IOS. I update the version of my watchOS. It's work : )